# perform sendkeys parallely in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a test case where i have to input text using selenium

```
driver.findElement(by).sendKeys()
```

function. I have to input text in 15 text fields individually by using this function.

This takes a lots of time to input text in each 15 text field.

I want to use this

```
driver.findElement(by).sendKeys()
```

function parallely in java in my one test case where input in 15 text field will done parallely which will save a lots of time.

Please any help how i can do this?

Comment: Just to be sure I got you the right way: You got one page. One this page are 15 input fields. You want them to be filled with the same string simultaneously?

Comment: yes...all 15 input fileds at the same time

Comment: I don't think that this is possible...If you would use phantomJs instead of a browser, it would cost you almost no time at all :-)

Comment: ok all this 15 input boxes have same locator stratgey or different

Comment: Why would you want to invalidate your tests by doing something that a user could not possibly do? If you don't want user-interactive tests, perhaps you shouldn't be using Selenium at all? You could save time that way...

Comment: @raj N ish Ku M ar ....i can handle the locator but how i can do this in java?

Comment: @Andrew Regan ....actually i want to reduce the test execution time... please suggest me a better way how i can do this...thanks

Comment: as @Andrew Regan said best way is to implement test as a normal user would do,but anyways if u want to do the way you want then its ok

Answer (score -1):

```
List<WebElement> checkbox=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(input[type="text"]));
int values[]=new int[];
values={"hi"."bye","data",3,67,};
  for(int i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++)
   {
        WebElement ele=checkbox.get(i);
        ele.sendKeys(values[i]);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile, let alone populate the fields in parallel.